# Can't Upload File PDF to folder with flask

Tags: python, web, flask

i want to upload a file pdf to folder but the file is not saved to the folder. i already read the documentation of upload in flask documentation, but the file isn't saved to my folder. i'm so confused there's no error

````
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, url_for, redirect, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:\\Users\\shyfa\\Documents\\Skripsi\\Program Fix\\uploads\\'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ['pdf']

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/test", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No File Part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No Selected File')
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('upload_file', filename = filename))
        
    return render_template('CobaInput.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mistake:  You want `filename.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower()`